# Travelling in a 2D grid

Tags: path-finding, performance, grid

I have a 2D grid (x,y coordinates) where each cell corresponds to each pixel of the interface that I am working with and I have a point A(x1,y1). Now I need to travel around in the grid, and I wont just move this single point, but would like to move a bunch of points together. Now what do you think is the best figure that I shall move, i.e. a circle with a predefined radius, or a square with a fixed side.

Also, once I decide upon the figure, I need to know, what all points are there in the figure, given a specific central point, and work with those points too.

I was thinking that a square would be a better idea, since I'll just have to check the if the difference of the coordinates of the point to be checked from the central point is less than side/2.

But I've heard that calculations with circle are not bad either.

Kindly suggest,

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you would like to "move" a geometrical shape on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write a method that draws the "bunch of points" around the central point.

   ```
   public void DrawMyPoints(Point center)
     {
        float radius = 10.0;
        MyPreferredGraphicsLib.DrawCircle(center, radius);
        //Draw a circle or a square, for example.
        //Most graphics libraries have dedicated methods for basic geometrical shapes.
     }
   ```
2. Every time you move the center point, clear the screen and redraw all the points:

   ```
   public void MoveMyPoints(Point newCenter)
     {
        MyPreferredGraphicsLib.ClearScreen(); //Usually automatic in anything post-Pascal.
        DrawMyPoints(newCenter);
     }
   ```